# Using pandas Series.map to generate multiple columns for a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I want to map a pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#series) to more than one column in a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) using some function `f(x)`.

Ideally I would use one function per column. But suppose there is some heavy computation with a lot of overlap, so I want all the computations to be done together (one for each row; the rows can be handled independently).

Is there an easier / more Pythonic ("pandastic"?) way than the following:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series('Joe Jill Stephen Mark Craig Alexander Emily Connor Cassidy'.split())

def f(x):
    """ computations that should be done in tandem
    (this is an easy example but the use case is for
    expensive operations that return multiple outputs)"""
    return (len(x), x[1:]) 

def map_series_to_columns(s, f, names):
    """ returns a DataFrame to extract series """
    s2 = s.map(f)   # create an intermediate result first
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {name: s2.map(lambda x: x[k]).rename(name) 
         for k,name in enumerate(names)},
        columns=names)

map_series_to_columns(s, f, ['len', 'slice'])
```

which returns the following (which is what I want):

```
   len     slice
0    3        oe
1    4       ill
2    7    tephen
3    4       ark
4    5      raig
5    9  lexander
6    5      mily
7    6     onnor
8    7    assidy
```

Along the way, a Series is created containing tuples (which is not what I need or want, but it seems unavoidable as an intermediate computation):

```
0          (3, oe)
1         (4, ill)
2      (7, tephen)
3         (4, ark)
4        (5, raig)
5    (9, lexander)
6        (5, mily)
7       (6, onnor)
8      (7, assidy)
dtype: object
```

I should add: I am not worried about the computation expense of the pandas calls; I expect the CPU bottleneck to be in my function, and it is an unavoidable bottleneck.

Comment: If your function returns a Series instead of a tuple then you can call `s.apply(f)` and it will return a DataFrame. Constructing a Series for each row might be more expensive though.

Comment: Something like `list(map(tuple,map_series_to_columns(s, f, ['len', 'slice']).values))` will be faster than apply .

Comment: @ayhan my real application uses regex's and some other stuff, so processing for each row is unavoidable. I can't vectorize. OH -- never mind, I misunderstood, you mean create a Series for each call to `f()`.

Comment: Yes, `return pd.Series({'len': len(x), 'slice': x[1:]})` followed by `s.apply(f)`. If Series construction is negligible compared to what f is doing, this might be a clearer solution.

Comment: The answer to this question is _wildly_ dependent on what it is you're trying to do. The moment you're forced to iterate over a DataFrame, you've lost all the reasons to use one. You may as well store a list and then use a for loop. Of course, the answer to this question is `pd.DataFrame((f(v) for v in s.tolist()), columns=['len', 'slice'])` and it works perfectly, but I don't think it is going to solve your actual problem. The answer to your real problem will depend on the problem.

Comment: The code above uses a DataFrame to exhaust a generator. If it does not answer your question, then you'll need to clarify, because this is unanswerable.

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't enough, given the lack of clarification.

Comment: You're expecting me to update my question from two months ago, which is no longer relevant to me, in less than 12 hours, on a weekend?

Comment: Yes... the fact that it isn't relevant to you isn't a reason to leave it half baked and unanswerable. You could also choose to delete it, if you don't want an answer anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```py
s = pd.Series('Joe Jill Stephen Mark Craig Alexander Emily Connor Cassidy'.split()).to_frame('Name')

s[['len','Update_name']] = s.apply(lambda s:(len(s['Name']),s['Name'][1:]), axis=1,  result_type="expand")
```

returns

```
    Name            len Update_name
0   Joe             3   oe
1   Jill            4   ill
2   Stephen         7   tephen
3   Mark            4   ark
4   Craig           5   raig
5   Alexander       9   lexander
6   Emily           5   mily
7   Connor          6   onnor
8   Cassidy         7   assidy
```